# Prove that $f$ is differentiable knowing that it is convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function and $a\in \mathbb{R}$. It is given that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is at least one positive 
>   real number, call it $r_n>0$, such that $$f(a+r_n)+f(a-r_n)-2f(a) < \frac{r_n}{n}$$
>   Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

Because $f$ is convex, we know that $f(a+r)+f(a-r)-2f(a) \geq 0, \: \forall r>0$. We also know that the left and right derivatives at $a$ exist, so it is left to prove that they are equal.

I tried to prove that $r_n \to 0$, since this and taking limits in the inequality from the statement (since $f$ is also continuous) would solve the problem. However, I couldn't finish this way and I feel that I don't use the convexity enough.

Comment: What does the convexity of $f$ imply about the function $$t \mapsto \frac{f(a+t) - f(a)}{t} - \frac{f(a) - f(a-t)}{t}$$ where $t > 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha_\pm =\lim_{h\to 0^\pm}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h$ be the left and right derivatives at $a$. We know that they exist and that $\alpha_+\ge \alpha_-$. Also, $f(a+h)\ge f(a)+h\alpha_+$ and $f(a-h)\ge f(a)- h\alpha_-$ for $h>0$.
We conclude
$$ f(a+r_n)+f(a-r_n)-2f(a)\ge (\alpha_+-\alpha_-)r_n$$
and from this $0\le \alpha_+-\alpha_-<\frac 1n$ for all $n$.